# Convert jQuery code to mootools 1.11

Tags: jquery, mootools

I use a slideshow which needs mootools 1.11 and my other code needs jQuery. 
Unfortunately as soon as I call the jquery library the slideshow is crashing.

Can I convert this little jquery code in to moo tools or pure javascript? How would the mootools code look like?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
    jQuery('.rgstitle, .rgsdescription').click(function(event) {
        window.open(jQuery('#rgslideshow-4574 a img:visible').parent().attr('href'), '_self');    
        return false;
    });
});
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried jQuery.noconflict() yet? -> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: there is NO excuse to use mootools 1.11 - its 4 yrs old. breaks in IE9 and potentially in modern ES5 shimmed browsers due to bind and some other differeces (it will fail to detect webkit/firefox past 3.6). upgrade...

Answer (score 1):

Leave the '$' for your mootools based code as it is. And Use 'jQueryDollar' for your jQuery codes. After adding the jquery library, use this :

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
var jQueryDollar = jQuery.noConflict();
// Do something with 'jQueryDollar'
jQueryDollar(document).ready(function(jQueryDollar) {
    jQueryDollar('.rgstitle, .rgsdescription').click(function(event) {
        window.open(jQueryDollar('#rgslideshow-4574 a img:visible').parent().attr('href'), '_self');    
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Now add mootools libraries just beneath:

```
 <script src="mootools.js"></script>
 <script>
     //'$' is now free for mootools
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple fix if you want the 2 libraries to work toghether. Put the following right after jQuery.js script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to check,
[Avoiding Conflicts with Other Libraries](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/) article from Jquery team.
I got the same problem and Solved jQuery slider and mootool news ticker :D